# Reading json from hidden input value

Tags: javascript

Trying to read JSON from hidden input value.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="hdn" type="hidden" value='{"products":{"id":100001,name:"Ram"}}'>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var jsonObj = document.getElementById('hdn').value;

            alert(jsonObj);

            alert(jsonObj.products.name);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to parse it as `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hdn').value)`

Note, I changed the way you were storing your JSON object, by adding the quotes to the `name` property.  I added as both console.log and an alert... mostly because I prefer console.log, but you originally had an alert in there.

Here's the updated (working) code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="hdn" type="hidden" value='{"products":{"id":100001,"name":"Ram"}}'>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hdn').value);

            console.log(jsonObj);
            console.log(jsonObj.products.name);

            alert(jsonObj);
            alert(jsonObj.products.name);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: code updated. still not getting the alert. working example http://jsfiddle.net/UHdpY/

Comment: I use ***ASP.NET*** and I have `<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$main$formHiddenField2" id="formHiddenField2" value="[
  {
    &quot;IdFabricante&quot;: 1,
    &quot;Fabricante&quot;: &quot;Fabricante 1&quot;,`